# google maps v3 marker coordinate change on imageMapType

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm tryng create a imageMapType of an aereal view taken at near 40° in apiv3 and keep markes on it, on the right location, when swiching from say "satellite" to "myimagemaptype".
I have no idea for a possible solution, or it is quite hard for me to set up one by myself, so, anyone can help or have alredy found a solution? 
(maybe im just missing something inside documentation.)

ty you all for help.

E.

edit: sorry, my mind is quite fuzzy right now, just missed the point.
edit 2: ty to Frank Tudor, examples comed handly. Im trying to write the code in a less messy way so i can post it here.
Still, the mian problem im facig is change or update automatically marker latLng to fit the aereal 45° map im buildig via imageMapType so they can keep the right position after swiching from standard to custom map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code example, I believe you are looking for the mapTypeControlOptions with this look for mapTypeId example: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE or google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID.

Here is example code.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/attachmentText?id=3089&aid=2943553346480020082&name=LOCAL_v3_basic_google.html&token=c027872819c8f0dce16f324cc5cbec1f

here is another example:

http://codeave.com/maps/g3_basic_MapTypeControlStyle.htm?u_log=9005

and here is the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeControlOptions

I hope this helps or at least gets you started.

Comment: ty, this is going to help.

Comment: im still looking for a clear way to explain the marker translation.
anyway, ill close thisone, ty again